# SSIS Excel connection works from app fails from deployed service

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I have a Windows service written in C# that calls an SSIS package written with SSIS 2008R2.  The package connects to an Excel spreadsheet.  It is executed as follows:

```
Application app = new Application();
Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsisPkgLoc"].ToString(), null);
DTSExecResult pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
```

When I install this service and the package runs, the package fails with

```
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_EXCEL_NOT_SUPPORTED: The Excel Connection Manager is not supported in the 64-bit version of SSIS, as no OLE DB provider is available.
```

However, if I call the same code from a WPF form, it executes as expected.  I know there are issues with the 64- vs. 32-bit connections from SSIS to Excel.  What's baffling me is that the same code is being called from both methods.

Any idea why running as a Windows service might be attempting to use a different driver / failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service needs to target a x86 architecture. Currently it's running in 64 bit mode and there is not an Excel driver available to it. When it launches the Application, it's pulling in the assemblies for the same architecture as the rest of the service and since it's in 64 bit space, it fails.

Comment: If only I could upvote twice.  Felt "configury" but obviously I had no clue where.  Thanks